# Find minimum/maximum value

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to find the points on the surface $y^2 = 25 + xz$ that are closest to the origin.
I don't have any idea how to approach this.

Can someone explain to me?

Comment: Do you know about lagrange multipliers?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

You want to minimize $\|(x,y,z)\|^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$ with the constraint $y^2=25+xz$. Use [Lagrange multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)!

Answer (score 1):

Set $x^2+y^2+z^2=d^2$. Now you have
$$d^2=25+x^2+xz+z^2=25+\left(x+\frac z 2\right)^2+ 3\frac{z^2}4\ge 25 $$
With equality iff $x=z=0$ (so $y = \pm5$ )